# How to display fetched records one by one

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working in angular-js, javscript and HTML. I am able to fetch a list of customer names and their details from the database, but I want to display those records one by one when I press next button. Can you please suggest me how to do this

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You pressed on some button , and some event will be fired and you will hit some API and response will be shown to the page . if yes lets say on button click ShowData function get triggered .

```
App.controller('CustomerCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
   $scope.ShowData =  CustomerService.Names().then(function(data){
    $scope.customers =  data
   })
}])
```

in Html

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
   <h3 ng-bind="customer.name"></h3>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerCtrl">
  <button value="Next" ng-click="next()">
  <div>
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
  </div> 
</div>
```

and your js file

```
App.controller('CustomerCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){    
$scope.ShowData =  CustomerService.Names().then(function(data){    
$scope.customers =  data;       

  })    
var cnt=0;    
$scope.next=function(){
   $scope.name=$scope.customers[cnt].name;      
  cnt++;
}

}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the above issue by using ng-repeat with limitTo filter.Here $scope.customers contains JSON array.Also limitTo is Controlled by using a variable i.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.i=1;
    $scope.customers = [{
        "firstName": "John",
      "place":"USA",
      "number":"78437375"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Anna",
      "place":"Asia",
      "number":"546464656"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Peter",
      "place":"Europe",
      "number":"24353535"
    }];
    $scope.showMoreCustomers=function()
    {
        
       $scope.i++;
    }
    $scope.showLessCustomers=function()
    {
      $scope.i--;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div   ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<button ng-click="showMoreCustomers()">+</button>
  <button ng-click="showLessCustomers()">-</button>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | limitTo:i">{{cust.firstName}},{{cust.place}},{{cust.number}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```